# See recently deleted questions in a user profile

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions

I got to review a [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/223518/error-in-yum-installation) today, that looked very much like another one I had [seen and commented on](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/223490/about-yum-installation). I tried to find the "original" via the users profile page, but it indicated the user only had one question on the main site.

I suspected deletion, went into the first post review queue, and found the original. However if I had not remembered that I had seen it there, I might not so easily have found the question.

Can the people with enough rep to view deleted posts, get a grace period (e.g. a day) in which the deleted post still show up in a list somewhere?

That way it is easier to check if someone if a new user is throwing away useful edits, to get rid of comments or for some other, possible inappropriate, reason.

The recently deleted posts could be shown tagged in the users profile and preferably as well in a "recently deleted" section of the 10K tools (the recently deleted section there, currently only seems to show "Community" deleted posts).

Comment: The 10k list does show posts deleted by other people besides Community, but doesn't show posts deleted by their owner (since that sort of thing doesn't normally require oversight; if somebody wants to delete their post they can feel free)

Comment: I think the point was a request to be able to check back on a history of someone deleting their own questions, though.